# Shell stucks after using editor inside docker container

Tags: bash, shell, docker, containers, editor

Every time I use an editor like nano or vim on a container shell(bash)

1. It won't open in full size window
2. The shell will stuck (Enter won't work) and will not work properly after saving the file (and exiting the editor).

I'm on OSX Sierra

nano editor :

[image]

Comment: how do you start bash on docker?

Comment: docker exec -it mycontainer bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly because bash was not properly started, should work better like this

`docker exec -it container-id /bin/bash -c "export TERM=xterm; exec bash"`

[TERM env](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-11.html) variable info.

Comment: Hi, this worked, but to be honest is too long to write every time. Maybe Docker has to take care of it (with an extra flag or something) otherwise I'd have to make it permanent for every container.

Comment: lol, you're lazy! If your OS is Linux you should explore how to use `bash history` and/or `bash alias`.

Comment: My OS is OSX and I do know how to use history and also there different containers or from different machines every time. The easiest would be to just work as it should.